# Precedence of concatenation: Is $5/7y$ equal to $(5/7)\times y$ or $5/(7\times y)$?

Tags: notation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do values attached to integers have implicit parentheses?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16502/do-values-attached-to-integers-have-implicit-parentheses)
>   [What is 48÷2(9+3)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33215/what-is-48293)
>   [What is “multiplication by juxtaposition”?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33240/what-is-multiplication-by-juxtaposition)

What is the precedence of the concatention operator when used for 
multiplication?

If it's the same as multiplication, 5/7y would mean (5/7)*y.

However, it also seems reasonable to see it as 5/(7*y).

I realize I can avoid the issue by writing "5y/7" or using explicit 
parentheses, but am curious about the "correct" answer.

Googling was surprisingly unhelpful: most results were about the 
precedence of string concatention in programming languages.

Comment: Duplicates: [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16502/do-values-attached-to-integers-have-implicit-parentheses), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31881/implicit-multiplication-order-of-operation), and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33215/what-is-48293)

Comment: You are right that it is confusing and should therefore be avoided.  I suspect that most people who write it are thinking $5/(7y)$.

Comment: "When there's doubt on how it's seen in others' eyes\always remember to parenthesize!"

Comment: I guess the right term is *juxtaposition* rather than *concatenation*. See this question [What is “multiplication by juxtaposition”?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33240/what-is-multiplication-by-juxtaposition)

Comment: PARI interprets 5/7*x as (5/7)x, just as a point of reference. I personally think the notation without parentheses is ambiguous and should be avoided.

Comment: @MichaelBoratko: I think this question is slightly different since we here have the symbol $/$ and not the other sign (that I don't know how to do in LaTeX).

Comment: @Thomas: If you don't know how to get a symbol in LaTeX, [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) is of great help. Assuming you meant the symbol $\div$, I've just used it to find that it is generated by the macro `\div`.

Comment: @Thomas The first question I linked to does use the $/$ symbol.

Comment: @MichaelBoratko: Fair enough.

Comment: No need to out quotes in the title, makes it harder to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you almost answered your own question:

> I realize I can avoid the issue by writing "5y/7" or using explicit parentheses.

I don't know of any "correct" way to interpret $5/7y$, and I don't believe that there is any. There are lots of notations in math that are not that clear, and the only answer is to make them clear. So I would never write $5/7y$ on a blackboard if I meant $5/(7y)$.

If you by $5/7y$ mean $5/7*y$, then from what I understand, when programming a compiler would interpret this as $5*y/7$.

Comment: Actually in the vast majority of programming languages, `5/7y` would simply be a syntax error, because multiplication needs generally be explicitly written with `*`. In C++11 it could, however, denote the division of the standard integer 5 by a user-defined numeric literal `7y` (which most likely will be the number 7 represented by an user-defined numeric type). Indeed, the only programming language I know where juxtaposition is interpreted as multiplication is Mathematica's; here indeed `5/7y` means $(5/7)y$.

Comment: @celtschk: You are right! I will edit

Comment: Speaking of Mathematica, IIRC [Singular](http://www.singular.uni-kl.de/) also interprets juxtaposition as multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

I believe concatenation strictly applies to the joining of two strings together. I would imagine that extending this to mathematical operations there would be parenthesis around the objects in order to avoid ambiguity, ie $$ 5/7 * y/x $$ would yield $$\dfrac{5}{7}\cdot\dfrac{y}{x}$$